# method not found

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm working on an application with three tabs plus a small view in which I created a sort of TopBar that contains some info and some buttons.

In the main application delegate I define:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{  
  ...
  // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window  
  [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];  
  //here we add the topBar:  
  topBarViewController = [TopBarViewController instance];  
  topBarViewController.appDelegate = self;
  [window addSubview:topBarViewController.view];
  ...
}

- (void)showReplyView
{
  self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = 
    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

as you can see I set the `.appDelegate` in the topBar to make some call back in the code of the topBar (ie: when I want to change the tab currently visualized)

Now in my TopBarViewController.h I have:

```
@interface TopBarViewController : UIViewController {
  MyAppDelegate *appDelegate;
  ...
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) MyAppDelegate *appDelegate;
-(void)testMethod;
```

and in the .m file:

```
@implementation TopBarViewController
@synthesize appDelegate;
...
-(void)testMethod{
  [appDelegate showReplyView];
}
...
```

When I build the project the compiler tell me that the showReplyView method doesn't exist.
I tried everything and I'm sure that there are no typo errors...

Is it possible that I can't reference to the delegate?
Thanks to anyone would help me...

Comment: Is it a typo that app delegate has different types in ivar and property definitions? and you should not store reference to delegate - better get it using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] method

Comment: Yes, it was a typo... sorry.
And thanks for the suggestion, but I preferred to do in this way so I don't have to cast the result of [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem:
in the `TopBarViewController.h` I was declaring `@class MyAppDelegate;` since I couldn't make an import (avoid the loop).
So the compiler was not able to find out which methods were declared.

To solve it I import the `#import MyAppDelegate.h` directly in the `TopBarViewController.m`!

Thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined `showReplyView` in the `@interface` for `MyAppDelegate`?